# Pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on assignment. I started with the struct:

```
struct figures_struct
{
    char figure_name[130];
    double figure_coordinates[1000000];
};
```

When I read name of the figure from the file, I stored it into the struct as follows:

```
strcpy(figures[i].figure_name,f_name);
```

Now I have to modify my code and need to use dynamic memory. I did:

```
struct figures_struct
{
    char figure_name[130];
    double figure_coordinates[100000];
};

struct figures_struct *figures = malloc(size * sizeof(struct figures_struct));
```

Now, how do I store figure name into my struct? `figures[i].figure_name` does not seem to be working.

Comment: its helpful if you include what error you see and what else you've tried.

Comment: What "does not seem to be working" is supposed to mean? There's nothing wrong with `figures[i].figure_name` by itself. `strcpy(figures[i].figure_name,f_name)` will work perfectly fine.

Comment: The *exact* same syntax for structure access will work. And both imply your index (i) will never exceed your dimension (size). Does your assignment require that you can *grow* your allocated number of structs over time, because that is an entirely different question (and answer).

Comment: It's interesting that the structure size shrank by a factor of 10 between the two versions.

Comment: I wouldn't use `strcpy()`, but `strncpy()`. Even if you are beginner, you shouldn't get used to dangerous patterns.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy(figures[i].figure_name, f_name);`

That will still work with pointers(as pointers and arrays are almost interchangeable in C)

Comment: Up until the parenthetical comment, I'd agree.  The parenthetical comment (currently _'as pointers and arrays are almost interchangeable in C'_) is not the reason why that continues to work, and isn't all that accurate as a statement.  Pointers and arrays are closely related; they are not interchangeable, especially not at the point where memory is allocated.  However, the reason that the `strcpy()` still works is that `figures[i]` is still a structure, just as it was before, so the same initialization technique works on the structure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah my bad, I used the word almost to mean exactly what you're telling me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Maybe the more appropriate thing to say would be that arrays can be used where pointer rvalues are required.

Answer (score 0):

It will work as soon as "i" is less than "size".